# Problems passing variables between view controllers

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am aware that this is extremely basic but I am passing variables between view controllers for the first time and I am having issues.

I'm just trying to take a user's name from a text field on one view controller and display it in a label on another. On the first view controller I have got:

```
import UIKit

var userName = ""

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBAction func enterUserDetails(sender : AnyObject) {
    userNameInput.text = userName
}

}
```

And on the other view controller I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

userWelcomeMessage.text = "Good \(currentTimeOfDay), \(userName)!"

}
```

The code runs but I don't get an output from the userName variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, that viewDidLoad is implemented in some other view controller, not `FirstViewController`, right?  How is `userName` defined in the scope of `viewDidLoad`?  You're going to have to assign `userName` on your second view controller somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Change that to

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController { 
    ...
    var givenUserName:String!
}  

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var userName = ""

   @IBAction func enterUserDetails(sender : AnyObject) {
        userName = userNameInput.text 
   }

   override func prepareForSegue(...) {
       if (this is your segue) {
           (new view controller).givenUserName = userName
       }
   } 
}
```

Or if you don't use segues, there's some place where you manually instantiate `SecondViewController` and you can assign its `givenUserName` there. But please **no global variables**.

Comment: I'm using segues for the storyboard but I don't really know much about segues at this point. Swift is my first language after a small amount of programming in Visual Basic 6 so I'm still learning the basics. I'll do some more research and then try to implement your suggestion once I understand it better.

Comment: No problem, I don't know any Swift books *yet*, but: take a look at the template code that appears if you select **Master-Detail app** with Swift in Xcode.